# Ein Mädchen im Kumpelmodus?

Tags: meaning, phrase

I was partying last weekend with a couple of friends and some of their acquaintances. There was a girl wearing a pretty sexy and not that long dress who said she was in **Kumpelmodus**.

What does that mean?

Comment: Well, what do you guess it meant? (And more interestingly, what happened next?)

Comment: We can deconstruct the word at face value, but that's something you can do just as well yourself. *Kumpelmodus = pal mode*. What that actually meant *in context* is impossible to tell because little, if any, context has been supplied. We can only guess she friendzoned you (or everyone).

Comment: "Ich bin im Kumpelmodus" heißt, "Ich such einen Lover, aber Du scheidest aus" (Im Zusammenhang mit dem Dress).

Comment: pretty direct way of friendzoning someone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

She was telling you beforehand that she was not looking for a hookup. An advance "let's just be friends", if you will. *Kumpel* is a German expression for buddy, mate, pal.

Answer (score 7):

She was telling you that she was not there for flirting.

A **Kumpel** is a friend, a pal, a buddy.

Basically, you've been preemptively friendzoned, as this might be called in certain corners of the internet ;-)

Comment: Rather, she friendzoned herself, didn't she?

Answer (score 3):

She was basically there to hang out and not looking for a hookup or anything romantic.

"*Kumpel*" = pal, buddy and "*modus*" = mode, so literally translated she said "I'm in pal/friend mode tonight.